# swift xcode error: "instance member 'name' cannot be used on type 'clothing_category'

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently building an ios app using swift on xcode and I keep getting the error `instance member 'name' cannot be used on type 'clothing_category.'`

I have set up a tableviewcell and I need to fetch the appropriate `clothig_category` in the clothing_categories array. The line that has the error is:  `cell.nameclothing_category.text = clothing_category.name`

Below is the full code:

```
class clothing_category: NSObject {
    let name: String!
    init (name: String) {
       self.name = name
    }
}

class categoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: Properties 

    // Create an array to hold the clothing.
    var clothing_categories = [clothing_category]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Load sample data
        loadSampleClothing_categories()
    }
        func loadSampleClothing_categories() {
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name:"Jackets"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Accessories"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Pants"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Color"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Tops"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Dressing for an Occaision"))



        // Load up the array when the view is loaded.

        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name:"Jackets"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Accessories"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Pants"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Color"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Tops"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Dressing for an Occaision"))

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return clothing_categories.count
    }

    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "categoriesTableViewCell"


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! catgeoriesTableViewCell
       //Fetches the appropriate clothing_catgeory for the data source layout.
        _ = clothing_categories[indexPath.row]
        **cell.nameclothing_category.text = clothing_category.name**
        return cell

    }
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I see where you have gone wrong. Naming conventions would of actually prevented this but anyway. You're actually accessing the name like it's a static property, when in fact it's an instance property. Doing something like this will solve your problem:

```
let category = clothing_categories[indexPath.row]
cell.nameclothing_category.text = category.name
```

Comment: "Naming conventions would of actually prevented this" ugh ain't that always the case with these >_>